# How to remove all string elements from a numpy object array

Tags: python, numpy

origin array is like:

```
array([nan, nan, 'hello', ..., nan, 'N', 61.0], dtype=object)
```

How can I remove all string from this array and get a new array with dtype float?

I know I can do this using python list:

```
[i for i in x if type(i) == float]
```

but this way will change `numpy.ndarray` to `list`, is there a way to do this in numpy?

Comment: Wrap that list with `np.array`.

Comment: Working with an object dtype array does not save any time compared to a list.  Both contain references to objects elsewhere in memory.  The fast, numeric `numpy` methods are not available for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like below.

```py
import numpy as np
a = array([np.nan, np.nan, 'hello', ..., np.nan, 'N', 61.0], dtype=object)
a = a[[isinstance(i, float) for i in a]]
```

Comment: The `where` isn't needed.

Comment: I got it. fixed it

Answer (score 0):

I am not seeing a way in pure `numpy` but if you are fine using `pandas` to return a `numpy` array:

```
import panadas as pd
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([np.nan, np.nan, 'hello', np.nan, 'N', 61.0], dtype=object)
pd.to_numeric(pd.Series(arr), errors='coerce').dropna().values
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use np.fromiter():

```
a = np.array([np.nan, np.nan, 'hello', ..., np.nan, 'N', 61.0], dtype=object)
r = np.fromiter((x for x in a if type(x) == float), dtype=float)

print(r)
#[nan nan nan 61.]
```

To further remove nan values:

```
r = r[~np.isnan(r)]
#[61.]
```